# Powershell convertto-html and an array hashtable

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to output the contents of my foreach to an array or object in the goal of using convertto-html to publish out a formatted table for me.

My latest try of it was using a hashtable but that didn't quite work out as it just made the contents of the table have no headers.

Basically i am trying to output the results of any applications in default website that contain folder XXX to a formatted html table with a column of application name, and the full path to XXX folder.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$getiisapp = Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site"
$myarray = @{}
foreach ($getiisapps in $getiisapp) {
$fullpath = $getiisapps.PhysicalPath
$fullname = $getiisapps.path    


if(Test-Path "$fullpath\XXX\") {
    $myarray.Add($getiisapps.path,$getiisapps.PhysicalPath)        
   }
}
```

this revision of it, puts the application names in the table header and the value in for the next row so i'm kindof just out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Have a look at existing solutions that use PSCustomObject to prepare hashtable for ConvertTo-Html.

Comment: it doesn't have to really be a hashtable but that is the closest thing to getting it to output in the right format for convertto-html i could seem to get.

Comment: Move `$myarray = @{}` initialization ahead of `foreach` loop. In any case, you could simplify your script: `$getiisapp | ConvertTo-Html -Property path, PhysicalPath`

Comment: That's actually how i had it, i've tried creating arrays with no luck. I'm not trying to output the entire getiisapp variable out, i'm trying to filter it by which apps contain the XXX folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not trying to output the entire *getiisapp* variable out, I'm trying
>   to filter it by which apps contain the `XXX` folder.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$getiisapp = Get-WebApplication -Site "Default Web Site"  | 
    Where-Object {
        $fullpath = $_.PhysicalPath
        Test-Path "$fullpath\XXX\"
    }
$getiisapp | ConvertTo-Html -Property Path, PhysicalPath
```